# Problema de recarga con Laravel Livewire y formulario Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, bootstrap, laravel-livewire

Estoy viendo un problema que me genera Livewire cuando uso **CUALQUIER** formulario Javascript. Utilice el siguiente formulario: https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/multi-step-form-wizard-30467045 **(Aunque probé otros formularios y me pasa con todos debido a los eventos de wire:model de livewire)**

El problema es que **WIRE:MODEL** me lleva a la primera sección y no puedo utilizar **WIRE:IGNORE** por que me anula comportamientos de SELECT relacionados.

En la **segunda** sección utilizo el siguiente formulario relacionado:

```
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="provincia">Provincia</label>
  <select wire:model="ubicacionSeleccionada" class="form-control" id="ubicacion">
       <option value=''>Seleccionar provincia</option>
       @foreach($ubicaciones as $ubicacion)
       <option value="{{$ubicacion->id}}">{{ $ubicacion->ubicacion }}</option>
       @endforeach                                          
  </select>
  </div>
                                        
    
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="tipopropiedad">Localidad</label>
   <select wire:model="area" class="form-control" id="localidad
         {{ count($this->areas)== 0 ? 'hidden' : '' }} ">
         <option value=''>Seleccionar localidad</option>
         @foreach($this->areas as $area)
         <option value={{ $area->id }}>{{ $area->name }}</option>
         @endforeach
   </select>
   </div>
```

Y esto no me permite usar el **WIRE:IGNORE** para anular los eventos.

El problema es que cualquier **WIRE:MODEL** genera un evento que me lleva el formulario a la primera sección. Pareciera ser un **REFRESH**

¿Alguien conoce como podría utilizar livewire sin tener este inconveniente?

*******EDICIÓN*******

**Componente**
Si bien tengo esta funcionalidad, la comenté para ver el si el problema continuaba y si persiste.

```
public function render()
{

    if(!empty($this->ubicacionSeleccionada)) {
        $this->areas = Area::where('ubicacion_id', $this->ubicacionSeleccionada)->get();
    }
    //CREAMOS CODIGO ALEATORIO Y LO ENVIAMOS A LA VISTA
    $caracteres = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z");
    $codigo = '';

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        $codigo .= $caracteres[rand(0, 35)];
    }

    return view('livewire.publication.publication-component', [
        'propiedades' => TipoDePropiedad::get(),
        'ubicaciones' => Ubicacion::get(),
        'categorias' => Category::get(),
        'codigoUsuarioPropiedad' => $codigo
    ]);
}
```

Y el método que recolecta los datos: Ahora lo tengo en modo prueba pero me trae bien todos los datos.

```
public function Publicar()
    {
       dd($this->area);
    }
```

El problema se basa en los campos WIRE:MODEL probé agregando tiempo de envío de eventos de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="text" wire:model.debounce.500ms="name">
```

Y esto **funciona hasta que se cumple el tiempo**. Por tal motivo se que todo es por el evento que genera Livewire. Pero no encuentro como solucionarlo.

> **SOLUCIÓN**

Encontré una forma de solucionar este inconveniente trabajandolo como un paginador, de la siguiente manera:
En el **componente** declaré la variable que va a hacer de contador y paginador.

```
// Paginador | contador
public $pasos;

// La inicializamos en cero 
public function mount()
{
    $this->pasos= 0;
}

// Al presionar el botón siguiente aumenta el contador
public function incrementar()
{
    $this->pasos++;
}

// Al presionar el botón atrás disminuye el contador
public function decremento()
{
    $this->pasos--;
}
```

En la **vista**

```
  // Mostramos la vista en base al valor de la variable del contador
    @if($pasos== 0)
       <div>contenido....</div>
    @endif
    
    @if($pasos== 1)
      <div>contenido....</div>
    @endif
    
// Aumenta el contador    
<button wire:click="incrementar()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Siguiente</button>

// Decrementa el contador
<button wire:click="decremento()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Atras</button>
```

Comment: Estás utilizando select2?

Comment: Hola, no. De hecho todos los código de Javascript los desactive y el problema persiste.

Comment: Podrías agregar tu componente?

Comment: Agregué en el final el código y una prueba que hice que se acerco bastante, pero sin éxito. Gracias @L.Flor

Comment: ¿Con vue.js tendré el mismo problema? pienso que a lo mejor livewire no cumple con lo que requiero.

Comment: Obviamente te retornará siempre a la primera sección porque está renderizando siempre esa vista. Lo que debes hacer es poner `wire:ignore` dentro de los `<li class="active" wire:ignore></li>`

Comment: Es un formulario de múltiples pasos en la misma vista. Tiene 8 secciones con más de 20 inputs y select. Se hace muy engorroso de leer en stackoverflow toda esa vista por eso no lo puse aquí. Pero probé de hacer lo que comentas y me desarma la vista y la duplica. Por otro lado con el wire ignore no me trae los datos para los select.

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/156#issuecomment-533843736

Comment: Justo me puse a desarrollar una nueva función para solucionar este problema. Muchas gracias @L.Flor voy a ver en profundidad el enlace, pero creo que la manera que utilice es una forma sólida. Me gustaría recibir tu devolución en base a lo solución que presento. Graciasss!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema desarrollé la siguiente solución, simple pero espero que les sirva a otros desarrolladores.

**COMPONENTE**

```
//Paginador
public $pasos;


public function mount()
{
    $this->pasos= 0;
}

public function incrementar()
{
    $this->pasos++;
}

public function decremento()
{
    $this->pasos--;
}
```

**VISTA**

```
@if($pasos== 0)
   <div>contenido....</div>
@endif

@if($pasos== 1)
  <div>contenido....</div>
@endif


<button wire:click="incrementar()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Siguiente</button>
<button wire:click="decremento()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Atras</button>
```

Por supuesto se puede condicionar mucho más para evitar errores.

¡Saludos!

Comment: Perfecto, no olvides marcar tu aporte como aceptado cuando el sistema te lo permita

Comment: Por cierto edita y explicalo por favor, así será mejor recibido por futuros lectores y lectoras